# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application SaveAs() method does not preserve encoding

Tags: c#, excel, csv, encoding

I'm having an issue saving excel files as CSV's and preserving the encoding in C#. Specifically, the following takes an excel file and saves it as a csv file with the same name, which is passed to the loadCsvData function, whose job is to insert the data into a database in an organized fashion. My issue is that the excel file contains fractional symbols which are not recognized in a csv format, unless i MANUALLY open each .xml            and save as csv (for some reason this works while the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application method SaveAs() does not):

```
            List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
            string fileName = (date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ".csv").Replace("/","");
            string excelFileName = (date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ".xml").Replace("/","");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Processing file: " + fileName);
            System.Console.ReadLine();

            // Open excel and save as csv. Then process the data
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\TAG\Desktop\TIP holdings\" + excelFileName);
            workBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\TAG\Desktop\TIP holdings\CSV Data\" + fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
            workBook.Close(false,"",true);

            data = loadCsvData(fileName);
            insertData(data);
```

Comment: I don't know the precise answer for this, but a common way to fix issues like this is to use Excel's macro recorder. Record the operation you perform in the UI as a VB macro, open it up in the macro editor and see what commands the macro calls. This should give you a clue about what parameters you'll need to pass to the `SaveAs` method. Have you tried setting the `TextCodepage` argument to the `SaveAs` method.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample file? Or, at least, a sample of the kind of encoding you are referring?

Comment: @RichardCook This is a good idea but so far all it gave me was to use an xlCSV format. I am not sure what you mean by the TextCodepage argument.

Comment: @varocarbas I need utf-8 if possible

Comment: To... ?! Also, I understand that these values are in different cells, isn't it?. Could you please be as detailed as possible in the exact conditions such that we can help you? Changing the encoding does not sound too logical, perhaps there is another reason.

Comment: `TextCodepage` is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx.